# Confidence interval for one sided hypothesis tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I am working on a drug trial where the sponsor wants to have a one sided 10% hypothesis test on the primary outcome. 
As a standard, we present both p-values and confidence intervals.

What will be the confidence interval I should look at to go with this one sided 10% hypothesis test?

Comment: Welcome to CV, ASJRM. What kind of one sided hypothesis test? T test? Z test? Something else? You can click the "[edit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/362528/edit)" link in the lower left to edit your answer and clarify.

Comment: Do you mean you want a hypothesis test using $\alpha =.10$? What test are you going to use, a $t$-test, a $z$-test, a $\chi^2$-test, something else? (What?)